# ruby-jwt encode, decode with RS256 algorithm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

It seems like we have always initialize and use the same private key when encoding and decoding a token in RSA256 algorithm:

```
payload = {:data => 'test'}
rsa_private = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
rsa_public = rsa_private.public_key

token = JWT.encode payload, rsa_private, 'RS256'
# eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0ZXN0IjoiZGF0YSJ9.c2FynXNyi6_PeKxrDGxfS3OLwQ8lTDbWBWdq7oMviCy2ZfFpzvW2E_odCWJrbLof-eplHCsKzW7MGAntHMALXgclm_Cs9i2Exi6BZHzpr9suYkrhIjwqV1tCgMBCQpdeMwIq6SyKVjgH3L51ivIt0-GDDPDH1Rcut3jRQzp3Q35bg3tcI2iVg7t3Msvl9QrxXAdYNFiS5KXH22aJZ8X_O2HgqVYBXfSB1ygTYUmKTIIyLbntPQ7R22rFko1knGWOgQCoYXwbtpuKRZVFrxX958L2gUWgb4jEQNf3fhOtkBm1mJpj-7BGst00o8g_3P2zHy-3aKgpPo1XlKQGjRrrxA
puts token

decoded_token = JWT.decode token, rsa_public, true, { :algorithm => 'RS256' }

# Array
# [
#   {"data"=>"test"}, # payload
#   {"alg"=>"RS256"} # header
# ]
puts decoded_token
```

But what is the best way t do that in a Rails 5.1 app ?

Comment: you mean, you'd like to generate a different key each time it is used ?

Comment: @ben, nope, the opposite. I used HMAC before, and could just use Rails generated secret key. With RSA256 it is different. I always have to use the same private key for encoding and decoding a token. That's why I'm asking and wonder if there are some tips and tricks abut its use in Rails because I have no private key provided and have to create it on my own: `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048`

Comment: Otherwise, if you create a new rsa private key and try to decode a token that was created rsa key generated previousely, you get `JWT::VerificationError: Signature verification raised`

Comment: i know that. I still don't understand your point sorry

Comment: why don't you put KEY=OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(2048) in an initializer ?

Comment: Because the methods `encode` and `decode` were defined as class methods. So if I define it in the constructor, it breaks the existing implementation (where we never call `MyWenTokenClass.new`, just `MyWebTokenClass.encode`. By the way, in JWT both methods are class methods as well: `JWT.decode(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to fix that.
So I have a class `JsonWebToken`with 2 class methods: `encode`and `decode`defined as follows:

```
class JsonWebToken

  ALGO = 'RS256'

  class << self

    def encode(payload, exp = 2.hours.from_now)
      # set expiry to 2 hours from creation time
      payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
      JWT.encode(payload, private_key, ALGO)
    end

    def decode(token)
      body = JWT.decode(token, private_key.public_key, true, algorithm: ALGO)[0]
      HashWithIndifferentAccess.new body
      # rescue from expiry exception
    rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::VerificationError => e
      # raise custom error to be handled by custom handler
      raise ExceptionHandler::ExpiredSignature, e.message
    end  

    private

      def private_key
        @rsa_private ||= OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate 2048
      end
  end

end
```

I just use another private static method to generate an rsa private key if needed.

Comment: Extremely helpful.  This worked.  Thank you.

Question: Are you using the @rsa_private anywhere else?

Comment: @Kobi: nope I don't use `@rsa_private` anywhere.

Comment: However, if you have the web server running on multiple instances, each of them now use a different private key. If the browser does not always connect to the same server instance (sticky sessions), a jwt created by server instance A will not be valid on server instance B.